# Installing Team Foundation Server - Requirements

Tags: version-control, tfs, installation

I'm Installing **Team Foundation Server** on my company's V-Sphere cloud.

And the IT department has asked my what are my system requirement for the virtual machines.

After reviewing the System Requirement on the Product page ,they look like minimum requirements.

My company has ~40 Developers & 20 Q.A Personal & ~10 PM.

I need to know:

- Disk Space
- CPU Power
- OS Version

The servers configuration

1. Main Server - Team Foundation Server & Reporting Server & SQL Database
2. Build Server - Build Controller & Some Build Agents
3. Proxy Server - TFS Proxy for Offshore team
4. SharePoint - will be using existing corporate SharePoint
5. Backup storage - nightly backup of the main server

And also the server configuration , if it makes any sense.

Comment: Why not go with the entry model virtual server your IT department has and then scale-up if their monitoring shows resources gets scarce?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for serverfault.com

Comment: @AaronS: Thanks , I will ask also there.

Comment: Dumb question, but you are going to install the proxy on a host near your offshore team correct?  Otherwise you lose any benefit the proxy can give you.

Comment: @RyanRinaldi: off course the proxy & one extra build machine will be at the offshore offices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice [Capacity Planning Poster posted by the VS ALM Rangers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/07/10/tfs-2010-capacity-planning-poster-refresh-posted.aspx).

You can use that as a nice reference.

Comment: Thanks you :) , Is there another reference you are familiar with?

Comment: What kind of reference are you talking about?

Comment: Another example like the one you gave.